# How to make the tabbar custom animation only occur for a certain view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom animation for when the tabs are selected, but instead I want that animation to only occur for when a certain tab is clicked. I am guessing it has to do with the instantiation of the `toView`. Error http://puu.sh/n5VuA/c3e886957e.png

```
class TransitioningObject: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
// Get the "from"nd "to" views
let fromView : UIView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
let toView : UIView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!


transitionContext.containerView()!.addSubview(fromView)
transitionContext.containerView()!.addSubview(toView)

//The "to" view with start "off screen" and slide left pushing the "from" view "off screen"
toView.frame = CGRectMake(toView.frame.width, 0, toView.frame.width, toView.frame.height)
let fromNewFrame = CGRectMake(-1 * fromView.frame.width, 0, fromView.frame.width, fromView.frame.height)

UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: { () -> Void in
toView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 560)
fromView.frame = fromNewFrame
}) { (Bool) -> Void in

transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }

}

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
return 0.35
    }
}
```

This is the view controller code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let animatedTransitioningObject = TransitioningObject()
    animatedTransitioningObject.animateTransition(UIViewControllerContextTransitionin) //I get an error here
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
  UIViewController* toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
  UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
  [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];
  toViewController.view.alpha = 0;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
    fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
    toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
      [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];

}];
```

}

Is how your Animation function should look.

Also if You want a pod that does this for you I would suggest checking out this pod

https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar[image: Animated Tab bar pod]